# bitbucket mercurial cannot see source codes in source column

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, bitbucket

I commit all my files into bitbucket. i try check in,revert file i deleted using netbeans and everything ok.  when i logined into bitbucket and select my repository (private). I unable to see my source codes inside "source" column

Comment: You should probably ask this to the bitbucket support staff or at their google group (see http://bitbucket.org/help/Home).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you "push" the commit to bitbucket?  A commit in mercurial will not publish changes the way it does in subversion or CVS.

You can do this on the command line:

```
hg commit -m "my commit message"
hg push
```

The push will send the changesets to the "default" location specificed in .hg/hgrc, which most likely is your bitbucket account, assuming you did your hg clone from bitbucket.

Comment: is there any way to config auto push in netbeans?

Comment: @cometta, pretty sure you can do it via a hook in your .hg/hgrc file. Something like "commit = hg push". See http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html and http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook